# can anyone explain this syntax? char *seats[14][7];

Tags: c, pointers

I came across this syntax: `char *seats[14][7];` in a c program. I'm a newbie to pointers, can anyone explain why is a 2-D array declared as a pointer and what use does it have?

Comment: It's a 2D array of pointers to `int`, for the purpose that the writer intended.

Comment: It's a two-dimensional array of pointers

Comment: It is actually invalid because only the first dimension can be left empty.

Comment: Show the context in which it appears. And, if it is compiling, tell us the compiler that is accepting it.

Comment: @ShayanHasanKhan: `char *seats[14][7]` is very different from `char *a[][]`. The former is defined by the C standard. The latter violates a constraint. When working with computers, you should be precise.

Comment: char *seats[14][7]; so this is for an airplane seat reservation system, and this syntax is to display seats which are reserved using * and x's.

Comment: so this is a matrix of pointers right?

Comment: thanks, illl keep that in mind @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's invalid code - a compiler error.

Because strictly speaking C doesn't have 2D arrays, it only has arrays of arrays (of arrays...). In this case you have declared an array of incomplete size where, each item is an array `int* []` of incomplete size. The C standard (6.7.6.2) does not allow such an item do be of incomplete type.

In case you change the code to `int* [x][y]` then it is an array of size `x` containing `int* [y]` arrays as items, where each such item is an array with size `y` of pointers to integer.

Answer (score 0):

int *a[][] - its mean matrix of pointers, for int variables, Each limb in this array can point to an int variable